# Undeclared identifiers in C

Tags: c, linux, kernel, printer-control-language

I've been trying to compile a program that uses PCL. However, I keep getting this error:

```
test.c:23: error: ‘PCL_CNT_TYPE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:23: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
test.c:23: error: for each function it appears in.)
test.c:23: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘i_result_list1’
test.c:24: error: ‘PCL_FP_CNT_TYPE’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:24: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘fp_result_list1’
test.c:27: error: ‘PCL_L1DCACHE_MISS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:28: error: ‘PCL_L2CACHE_MISS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:30: error: ‘PCL_MODE_USER’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:33: error: ‘PCL_SUCCESS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:47: error: ‘i_result_list2’ undeclared (first use in this function)
test.c:47: error: ‘fp_result_list2’ undeclared (first use in this function)
```

Any ideas why?

I have libpcl1{-dev} installed in me machine, so I'm wondering what else is necessary to make this works.

If you need further inforamtion just let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Put:

```
#include <pcl.h>
```

at the top of the file.  You will also need `-lpcl` when linking.  E.g.:

```
gcc program.c -lpcl -o program
```